# How to store JSON string into SQLite3?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, sqlite

I want to manage sqlite in application side. I converted NSArray to Json string But when i tried to inserting record in table of sqlite, I'm geeting `near "is_service": syntax error`. "is_service" is first field of my Json string

```
-(BOOL)InsertProduct:(Product *)product_obj
{
    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into tbl_product_list values(null,\"%@\",\"%@\")",
                       product_obj.product_id,product_obj.JsonString];
    [self executeQuery:query];
    if (self.affectedRows != 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

+(NSString*)ArrayToJson:(NSArray*)array
{
    NSData *jsonData1=[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:array options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
    NSString *jsonString=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:jsonData1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if(jsonString.length==0 || jsonString==nil)
    {
        return @"";
    }
    return jsonString;
}
```

If I passed, "abc" in placed on jsonString then Data has added successfully.

Please any one help me, how to I stored json string into Sqllite

Comment: `is_service`   type is `varchar`?

Comment: The Json string is not properly formatted as string like, I think "is_service" should be errorless if you can write it \"is_service\". (With backward slashes). So I think better way to save is, convert the json to Data form and save in Sqlite 3. Hopefully that will work out. Let me know then.

Comment: Try with :       `NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into tbl_product_list values(null,\"%@\",'%@')",
                        product_obj.product_id,[product_obj.JsonString UTF8String]];`

Comment: did you use FMDB ?

Comment: can you share your table schema and a sample json string